# Define object property type in html template (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an issue with recognizing the object type in the HTML template in Angular.

I have defined the object type as follows:

```
export interface ToolbarControlConfig {
  type: ControlType;
  toolbarControlOptions: ToolbarControlOptions;
}

export enum ControlType {
  BUTTON = 'BUTTON',
  DROPDOWN = 'DROPDOWN',
}

export interface ToolbarControlOptions {
  event?: () => void;
}

export interface ButtonControlOptions extends ToolbarControlOptions {
  label?: string;
}

export interface DropdownControlOptions extends ToolbarControlOptions {
  options: any[];
}
```

In the HTML template, I would like to handle elements for each type and use their properties:

```
<div *ngFor="let control of _controls">
  <button
    *ngIf="control.type === controlTypes.BUTTON"
    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light px-2"
    type="button"
    (click)="control.toolbarControlOptions.event()"
  >
    {{ control.toolbarControlOptions.label }}
  </button>
</div>
```

In the HTML template, I would like to handle elements for each type and use their properties:

```
<div *ngFor="let control of _controls">
  <button
    *ngIf="control.type === controlTypes.BUTTON"
    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-light px-2"
    type="button"
    (click)="control.toolbarControlOptions.event()"
  >
    {{ control.toolbarControlOptions.label }}
  </button>
</div>
```

Despite this, I receive a message saying "**Unresolved variable label**". Is there any way to access the appropriate properties of the object depending on its type? I have tried various methods, such as:

```
toolbarControlOptions: ButtonControlOptions | DropdownControlOptions;
```

or defining in HTML:

```
(control.toolbarControlOptions as ButtonToolbarControl).label
```